# Insert manually into a table by SQL statement, but key is autoincremented

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a table of users and the `id` column is the primary key and auto incremented.

I want to just try and add user manually by this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, username, password)  
VALUES (?, Mike, Mike);
```

but I don't want to specify the `?` value, just want to add to the next row.

Thanks everyone, I forgot to set the id column to auto increment. it works now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So just don't use it...do it like this..

And be sure you use single quotes for inserting `strings`

```
INSERT INTO table_name (username, password)
VALUES ('Mike', 'Mike');
```

As you said your field is `auto incremented`, SQL will automatically increment the value of the `id` field by 1

Answer (score 12):

If you want to manually insert a value to an auto incremented column you can use the IDENTITY_INSERT of sql. for example

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON
insert into MyTable(id, name) values (1,'asdf');
insert into MyTable(id, name) values (3,'htgfds');
insert into MyTable(id, name) values (123,'dsfg');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
```

you can read more here
[IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If id is a auto incremented value just leave that column out of the insert and it will fill in with the auto incremented value. For example from BOL [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=SQL.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
)

INSERT new_employees
   (fname, minit, lname)
VALUES
   ('Karin', 'F', 'Josephs')

INSERT new_employees
   (fname, minit, lname)
VALUES
   ('Pirkko', 'O', 'Koskitalo')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job for you:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (username, password)
VALUES('username_u','password_p');
```

The autoincrement value will be automatically added by SQL.